# Why am I getting a JavaScript compiler error when trying to publish changes to my intercom tag in Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

This is my tag:

```
<script>
    window.intercomSettings = {
        app_id: "fanwstw2"
    };
</script>
<script>
    (function() {
        var w = window;
        var ic = w.Intercom;
        if (typeof ic === "function") {
            ic('reattach_activator');
            ic('update', intercomSettings);
        } else {
            var d = document;
            var i = function() {
                i.c(arguments)
            };
            i.q = [];
            i.c = function(args) {
                i.q.push(args)
            };
            w.Intercom = i;

            function l() {
                var s = d.createElement('script');
                s.type = 'text/javascript';
                s.async = true;
                s.src = 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/fanwstw2';
                var x = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
            }
            if (w.attachEvent) {
                w.attachEvent('onload', l);
            } else {
                w.addEventListener('load', l, false);
            }
        }
    })()
</script>
```

This is the error message

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue as well, and I believe it's because GTM, which is based on the ES5 engine, is seeing ES6 code and trying to parse it as ES5. It is likely coming from your `l()` function declaration within the `if` block. Try to move that out of the `if` block, like just before it and compile the tag again, like this:

```
(function() {
    var w = window;
    var ic = w.Intercom;

    // moved this out of if block
    function l() {
        var s = d.createElement('script');
        s.type = 'text/javascript';
        s.async = true;
        s.src = 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/fanwstw2';
        var x = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    }

    if (typeof ic === "function") {
        ic('reattach_activator');
        ic('update', intercomSettings);
    } else {
        var d = document;
        var i = function() {
            i.c(arguments)
        };
        i.q = [];
        i.c = function(args) {
            i.q.push(args)
        };
        w.Intercom = i;

        if (w.attachEvent) {
            w.attachEvent('onload', l);
        } else {
            w.addEventListener('load', l, false);
        }
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any issue with your code, maybe it's the parser being overly awkward. It could also be caused by you wrapping within an IIFE.

How about changing this line below (just to rule it out being weird)..

```
ic('update', intercomSettings);
```

To this...

```
ic('update', w.intercomSettings);
```

Comment: Thanks, Zinc - I forgot to mention that this is a SPA - will that have any bearing? Although it was working fine before when testing.

Comment: Yeah probably - what is line 6, char 243? Does that point to your code base somewhere?

Comment: Is intercomSettings (in the scope of the anonymous function) and w.intercomSettings (global variable) necessarily the same variable ? I think that might be the thing  that throws the parser off.

Comment: Try passing window into the iife and referencing it with 'w'

Comment: It could also be the IIFE. Maybe that coupled with your SPA it causing it to break down. You couod just enable ES6 like it suggests to shut it up