# Javascript Compiler Error in Google Tag Manager: this language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better

Tags: javascript, css, google-tag-manager

I'm getting the following error message in Google Tag Manager:

> Error at line 6, character 282: this language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: block-scoped function declaration. Use --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6 or ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT or higher to enable ES6 features.

[when adding this Intercom snippet tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxq0H.png)

```
<script>
    window.intercomSettings = { app_id: {{intercom_chat_widget_id}} };
</script>

<script>
    (function () { var w = window; var ic = w.Intercom; if (typeof ic === "function") { ic('reattach_activator'); ic('update', intercomSettings); } else { var d = document; var i = function () { i.c(arguments) }; i.q = []; i.c = function (args) { i.q.push(args) }; w.Intercom = i; function l() { var s = d.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/{{intercom_chat_widget_id}}'; var x = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x); } if (w.attachEvent) { w.attachEvent('onload', l); } else { w.addEventListener('load', l, false); } } })()
</script>
```

For this section of the code `i = function () {`

Comment: Please don't include images of text, you need to include the text directly in the question. Google Tag Manager allows you to inject code (tags) into the users browser session: someone has written a tag that uses a version of JS too new for the target browser.

Comment: Please include the code here.

Comment: Hey guys, Okay thanks for the information - I thought it would be easier to isolate the character with an image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a JavaScript compiler error when trying to publish changes to my intercom tag in Google Tag Manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440623/why-am-i-getting-a-javascript-compiler-error-when-trying-to-publish-changes-to-m)

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440623/why-am-i-getting-a-javascript-compiler-error-when-trying-to-publish-changes-to-m/48447625#48447625

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in Google Tag Manager:

```
<script>
    window.intercomSettings = { app_id: {{intercom_chat_widget_id}} };
</script>

<script>
    (function () { var w = window; var ic = w.Intercom; if (typeof ic === "function") { ic('reattach_activator'); ic('update', intercomSettings); } else { var d = document; var i = function () { i.c(arguments) }; i.q = []; i.c = function (args) { i.q.push(args) }; w.Intercom = i; var l = function () { var s = d.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/{{intercom_chat_widget_id}}'; var x = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x); }; if (w.attachEvent) { w.attachEvent('onload', l); } else { w.addEventListener('load', l, false); } } })()
</script>
```

What has changed here is that

`function l() { ... }`

has been changed to

`var l = function () { ... };`

Answer (score 0):

## You need to declare a variable using the var keyword.

You currently compare something to a non-existing variable, you also use strict equality, which is impossible because there is no type to qualify the strict equality to, vinoaj workaround is what you want.